# Enable button a checkbox is checked with jquery.load

Tags: jquery

The code below works fine when the checkboxes are within the page itself. When the content in question is loaded from a jquery `.load` it doesn't register the checkboxes.

The `html` code below is displays within `<div id='output'></div>`. It works fine when I move it outside that div.

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').change( function() {
        $('#output').load('/process.php',{dropdown: $(this).val()});
    });

    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        $('#continue').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
    });
});
```

***HTML for process.php***

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the on() method to account for elements added to the DOM through AJAX. Try changing this -

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
    $('#continue').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
});
```

To this -

```
 $('body').on('click', '.checkbox', function(){
     $('#continue').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Works perfectly, then I tested it by clicking the cancel button. Which is `<button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>`. When I click it, the continue button doesn't reset to a disable state (the checkbox is uncheck).

Comment: You didn't include any information about a cancel button in your original post so I didn't cover it.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your `checkbox` handler to

```
$("body").on("click", ".checkbox", function(){
    $('#continue').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should try it via live binding

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...

    $(document).on( 'click', '.checkbox', function(){
        $('#continue').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
    });
});
```

this way allows you to listen to events also an object that are declared after the event binding was done.